# Apply retina 4 form factor button not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

`Xcode 4.6.2`

I have a storyboard project and recently the `apply retina 4 form factor button` is only working on the initial view controller, all the other ones stay the same standard size and do not expand.

I dont think I changed anything, and have no idea why it has stopped working.

Has anyone encountered this? What is the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each of your View Controller as its **Wants Full Screen** checked.

You can find it in the **Attributes Inspector** under **View Controller**, **Layout**.

[image: Xcode]

Comment: I just tred this with no luck. Interestingly the initial view controller (the only one working) does not have that checked.

Comment: Also I just noticed if I have the initial view controller selected and then press the retina form button the change does take affect across all the view controllers. But if any other view controller is selected or none at all only the initial changes.

Comment: I have not used storyboards much - but this fixed many of the MonoTouch samples (on github) that are using NIB and had issues on the iPhone5 (iPod5) screen resolution.